# Google earth plugin alt 10.00 error on IE

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I insert a simple map on my website, but just on Internet Explorer it doesn't work. I tested it on IE8 and IE9, but it gives me a white screen with "ALT 10.00" written on it.

I'm using version 7.0.1.8244 of the plugin Google Earth on Windows.

Any ideas why this is happing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, this was happing b/c i was resizing the div that the google earth was in it, I use a fixed height and width works well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you got that version of the plug-in (unless maybe you subscribe to the developers group?)

The latest official version is 6.2.0.5905 which claims to have fixed the issue you are mentioning. [See here for details](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/releasenotes).

If you update to 6.2.0.5905 and still see the problem, perhaps you should join the discussion on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=701).